# Automatic Reverse Segues

Tags: swift

My app make a telephone call from my collection view controller. After the call app shows home page. Call is not returned to called controller.

I put break points and checked execution flow. Then I could realise that call returned to called controller. But after that some internal codes are running and automatically segue to home page view controller (initial view controller). I don't know anything about internal execution like

```
UIKit-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]:
    0x1891f93b4 <+0>:  stp    x22, x21, [sp, #-48]!
    0x1891f93b8 <+4>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #16]
    0x1891f93bc <+8>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #32]
    0x1891f93c0 <+12>: add    x29, sp, #32
    0x1891f93c4 <+16>: mov    x19, x4
    0x1891f93c8 <+20>: mov    x20, x2
    0x1891f93cc <+24>: mov    x21, x0
    0x1891f93d0 <+28>: mov    x0, x3
    0x1891f93d4 <+32>: bl
```

Comment: what u want ...please clear you question 1st ?

Comment: After the tele call i have to stay in the called controller...What can i do...pls give me a suggession

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could track my problem..For some other reason I put a line of code inside the following App delegate method like:-

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

```
    window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

}
```

I commented the line of code and everything work fine...Thank God!!!!!